# PHP script won't render in browser - just displays the code

Tags: fedora, php, httpd

I use Fedora 17 on my laptop, and I am trying to do some web development work on it. I have installed Apache, MySQL and PHP on the laptop (following this guide when it comes to what software to install: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-fedora-10-p5). I can load web pages, but I am unable to load PHP pages properly. All that happens is that the actual code of the of the script is displayed in browser.

I've checked to see if mod_php is installed, and it is. I thought that maybe PHP was turned off globally, but I don't think it is. I must stress actually, that although the guide that I put the link to on this post does talk about turning PHP globally off, I haven't done this. I have just installed the software. But anyway, I have tried to look for the php.conf files in the httpd/conf.d directory, but nothing is there. I've also created a file which includes `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, but even this is displayed as plain text and not working.

I'm quite confused about why it's not working. I remember having a similar issue before, but that was back in 2009, and I haven't experienced this problem since.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
I've checked the httpd.conf, and looked at the LoadModules section. There is no mention of loading PHP in there. I've added the line and then httpd fails to start. I then removed that line I added, and checked the modules directory. Again there is no mention of PHP there either.

I went to install mod_php with yum again (like I've done with all of the packages), and it comes back saying that the package is already installed.

Comment: That's the problem with guides, you don't get a deep understanding of how it works by them.

Comment: True but it also gives you a good starting point with a subject, which I feel is a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let [apache2](/questions/tagged/apache2) enable the module with the `a2enmod` command. This tool will help identify if there's any issues with you installed libphp5 module

```
shell~> sudo a2enmod php5
shell~> sudo apachectl -M | grep php5
Syntax OK
 php5_module (shared)

shell~> sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

More info about enabling/disabling apach2 modules [here](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-enable-and-disable-apache-modules/)

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/httpd/conf` or `/etc/apache2/conf` depending on distro.

edit your `httpd.conf` and make sure these are included right below existing modules.

```
LoadModule php5_module   modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```